# Which windows platform select for windows app with proxy traffic features

Tags: windows, winapi, iframe, proxy, platform

Hi I am want try create application for windows platform on C++ and don't know which platform select Universal Windows Platform (UWP) or C++/Win32. I am don't have many experience on windows and want ask advice.
Now I am want describe want app should do:
I am want create app when where user can open web site on this application and if site blocked on user country, all traffic will be go throught proxy, but I am will need detect when user on this web site open for example player with movie and disable proxy for this traffic, will be need check iframe of content in website.

What platform select if my two main goal of app it's sent access to website throught proxy IF it need and SECOND it's check iFrame of webSite and disable proxy. Also I am need create fine GUI.

What are you think about that?

Comment: UWP apps run in a sandbox (there are some tweaks but it's still quite limited in terms of security, low level access and deployments in many ways, even if this has been loosened these last years). On the other way, it's much powerful than standard Win32 for UI apps (unless you use frameworks over Win32 such as Qt). From what you say, I'd go for Win32. Note that you can also use some of WinRT APIs (that's what UWP is built on) from a Win32/desktop apps. Also check the coming WINUI3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/ supposed to reunion all that ... mess

Comment: Thank you for advice,  very useful information for me.

Comment: If you don't have a reason to target the Universal Windows Platform, go with a classic Desktop application. @sim You can use practically the entire API surface of the Windows Runtime in a desktop application. Plus [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/). That doesn't leave much to be desired.

Comment: @IInspectable - there are still many WinRT apis you can't use with Win32, including packaged ones, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader